multiline node in tikzpicture environment
In a tikzpicture environment I'm tying to get a node that has rounded corners and a multi-line text.
The variable [box] is defined as follows:
  [box/.style={rounded corners,thick,draw=black,
  minimum width=2cm,minimum height=1cm}]

In the following example, line wrap fails:
  \node at (0,0) [box] (1A) {First line\\second line)};
  

This example produces "extra }" error
  \node at (0,0) [box] (1A) {\parbox {first line \\ second line}};

I intend to draw line between two horizontal boxes, one with rounded corners and the other with normal corners. Anything wrong constructing a second definition for a box such as for [Box]?

align= is indeed the usual way to get a multiline node
(you should not also need all the parbox part)

You can also use [text width=...].  [align] is roughly the same as a single column tabular, while [text width] is more like using a \parbox.

It is not clear what you after. Maybe for something like this?

Above image is draw with the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Box/.style={thick,draw=black,minimum width=25mm,minimum height=10mm,align=center},
box/.style={Box, rounded corners,thick,draw}
                    ]
\node[Box] (1A) at (0,0)        {John Dukes\\ (1849-- 1933)};
\node[box, right=of 1A] (1a)    {Janie Shelley\\ (?--1956)};
\draw (1A) -- (1a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comparison it with code in your answer shows, that your code is erroneous, errors are listed in log file (missing $). Also text is not in two lines and use of parbox is superfluous.

I stumbled around and would like to know if this code, which happens to work, is valid.
My intent is to construct a genealogical descent chart, and the code represents the initial couple.
`

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Box/.style={rectangle,thick,draw=black,minimum width=25mm,minimum height=10mm,align=center},
box/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,thick,draw=black,minimum width=25mm,minimum height=10mm,align=center}
]
\node[Box] at (0,10) [rectangle] (1A) {\parbox{20mm}{\centering John Dukes\(1849-- 1933)}};
\node[box] at (3,10) [box] (1a) {\parbox{20mm}{\centering Janie Shelley\(?--1956)}};
\node at (1.5,9) (node) {x};
\draw (1A) -- (1a);12.  \draw (1A) -| (node);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


It's syntactically ok, as far as I can see. However, nobody can test it unless everybody interested takes the burden to remove all "line numbers". Suggestions: romove numbers + mark as code // Unless it IS a solution, it's better to move it as an extension to your question.
